# How to do a "where x in ..." statement in a SAS data step

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have a large SAS data table that has a bunch of metrics for my whole base customer population (Master_v01).  I have a separate data table that has a list of customers that I want to exclude from my analysis (Excluded_Cust).

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
data Master_v02;
set Master_v01;
where cust not in (select cust from Excluded_Cust);
run;
```

Is this possible?

If not, what is the best way to achieve my desired goal, to get my base table with those customers I want excluded removed from the data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using Macro variables with the where clause:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select
        quote(cust)
    into
        :cust_exclude
    separated by
        " or cust ne "
    from
        Excluded_Cust
    ;
quit;

data Master_v02;
    set Master_v01;
    where cust ne &cust_exclude;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

My data step code is a bit rusty, but you can do this by looking up the value and checking for a match.  I think this goes as:

```
data Master_v02;
    set Master_v01;
    set Excluded_Cust key=cust;
    if _iorc_ = 0 then delete;
run;
```

Of course, an index on `cust` in `Excluded_Cust` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I can think of:

1.PROC SQL

```
proc sql;
  create table Master_v02 as
    select * 
      from Master_v01
      where cust not in (select cust from Excluded_cust);
quit;
```

---

2.DATA STEP MERGE

First sort Master_V01 and Excluded_cust datasets by cust, then:

```
data Master_V02;
  merge Master_V01 (in=Mast)
        Excluded_cust (in=Excl);
  by cust;
  if Mast and not Excl;
run;
```